# Manually sync multiple devices through iCloud

Tags: iphone, ipad, data-synchronization, icloud, ipod

We have an iPad and iPhone that I know we can set up to sync through iCloud. We also have several iPods. Will setting up iCloud for the iPad and iPhone affect our ability to manually sync the iPods?

Answer (score 1):

No, it won't affect your ability to manually sync the iPods.  Although you should clarify precisely what you m ean by "manually sync", as this could mean numerous things: an iTunes data backup of the device, music & media transfers, metadata syncing, purchase syncing, Contact syncing, etc.